# Date Comparison in JSON Schema Validation (Using JaySchema)

Tags: node.js, validation, jsonschema

Has anyone been able to do any sort of date comparison while using the [JaySchema schema library](https://github.com/natesilva/jayschema)?

I'm looking to have 2 fields in my schema, "startDate" and "endDate", and during the validation, I want to be able to ensure that the "startDate" value is a valid date-time that occurs prior to the "endDate" value.

Ideally, I'd like to do this with the built in library functionality, but if that's not possible, and anyone knows how to add custom validation checks, I'd love to hear that solution as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The JSON Schema standard (currently) doesn't support this kind of inter-property constraint.  This functionality would be enabled by a proposed keyword in v5 (`$data`), but it's not definitive which properties/features are included for the next version.

Comment: Thanks @cloudfeet, but I was asking more specifically for functionality within the NodeJS JaySchema Library (https://github.com/natesilva/jayschema), and less for JSON Schema standard...

Comment: Ah, OK - you asked about "built-in library functionality", and AFAIK JaySchema is a straight-up implementation of JSON Schema, which would mean that any solution would have to be a custom check.